# Error message while starting JBoss server:Port 9303 already in use

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I am getting below error message  while starting my Jboss 1.5 server. Kindly help me out with suggestions to fix this issue.

The Jboss servers stays up for matter of minutes and immediately it stops working with the below error message.

Kindly help.

```
2015-11-21 07:06:12,922 INFO  [org.jboss.web.WebService] (main) Using RMI server codebase: http://jboss URL:9303/
2015-11-21 07:06:12,982 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Start: name=jboss:service=WebService state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
java.lang.Exception: Port 9303 already in use.
  at org.jboss.web.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:233)
  at org.jboss.web.WebService.startService(WebService.java:322)
  at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:376)
  at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:322)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something at your system is running at the port 9303. You can either set port offset or change port of the service which is going to run at the port 9303.

To change port in JBoss 5 is something like:
run -c server_instance_name -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01

For test try to kill a service which is using port 9303 and try to run JBoss.